# Domain name with https and without www doesn't work

Tags: domain-name-system

I have setup custom domain for google-site, with namecheap as domain name provider.

I'm referring to the documentation of https://support.google.com/sites/answer/9068867?hl=en and https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9252/2208/how-do-i-add-my-domain-to-google-sites

Here's my setup in namecheap

[image]

However, not all domain are working

- http://wenote.me (works)
- https://www.wenote.me (works)
- http://www.wenote.me (works)
- https://wenote.me (NOT WORKING)

The one which starts with https, and without www doesn't work.

Any idea how I can make it work? Currently, I didn't purchase SSL cert from domain provider. Is that the reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: What exactly happens which makes you say "it does not work"? Please tell the exact steps you take and what exactly happens.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your Let's Encrypt HTTPS certificate is issued to "www.wenote.me", not "*.wenote.me". Your clients will get an SSL error when they try to access "wenote.me".
2. You have no DNS record for "wenote.me". Upon checking the response to a DNS query for "wenote.me", it does not return a ghs.googlehosted.com address like the response for "www.wenote.me". You may want to convert your "www" records to wildcard records if namecheap allows you to do so.

Comment: `*.wenote.me` would not match `wenote.me`